# is fail/0 the same as 1=2?

Tags: prolog

The predicate `fail/0` in prolog can be useful, for example to test for termination.

```
?- q, fail.
```

If this query terminates, then we know the query `?- q.` also terminates.

**Question**

Is `fail/0` equivalent to any goal that fails, eg `1=2`?

Is the following test the same as above?

```
?- q, 1=2.
```

Comment: Short answer, yes, they are the same for this use case.

Comment: `1=2`, although logically equivalent, fails *slower* than `fail`, because it has to be calculated.

Comment: `1=2` is a simple unification, it does not require calculation.

Answer (score -2):

One should not presume fail be completely equivalent to "any" goal that fails upon evaluation. In some cases there could be residual effects.

They are, simply put, different evaluations.

Comment: Hi Jacob. Can I ask what you mean by (true, fail), then, (true) ? I understand the  other comments about some evaluations taking longer, but I suspect your comment is different?

Comment: Yes, you mentioned: "If this query terminates, then we know the query ?- q. also terminates". Supply true for q, or even the dreaded repeat...

Comment: I'll also say 1=2 is an example here. You'll need to really define "equivalent". Also see dif/2 for more complex situations.

Comment: if q :- true. then surely q terminates, as does ?- true, fail. What am I missing?

Comment: You're right— edited. However, q may have residual effects; one should say say iff "q :- true."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).